# using curl against my IDN doesn't work right; browsers are OK

Tags: apache-2.2, curl, unicode, idn

I've registered www.❺➠.ws, which goes to the same IP as www.naildrivin5.com.

```
curl www.❺➠.ws
```

returns the homepage of www.naildrivin5.com.  No problem.  I modify apache to use name-based virtual hosts as follows:

```
<VirtualHost the.ip.address.here:80>
ServerName xn--dfi5d.ws
DocumentRoot /home/foo/xn--dfi5d.ws/html
```

(the xn--dfi5d.ws is the *punycode* version, and my understand is that is how you set up apache for IDNs)

Both Firefox and Safari successfully find the *new* homepage I have configured.

However, curl is not working quite right.  `curl www.❺➠.ws` **still** returns the www.naildrivin5.com homepage, while `curl xn--dfi5d.ws` returns the www.❺➠.ws hompage.

I tried using `-H "Host: www.❺➠.ws"` to see if setting that header explicitly was required, but it seems not.

I'm running curl on OS X and pasting those characters into the Terminal.app.

My main concern is that I've properly set up Apache to correctly route requests to www.❺➠.ws to the right place (i.e. **not** to www.naildrivin5.com).

Any curl experts have some suggestions on how to diagnose this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get the naildrivin5.com site when I go to www.❺➠.ws or www.xn--dfi5d.ws in Chrome. If I leave off the www, I get the ❺➠.ws site.

You need to add the case for www:

```
<VirtualHost the.ip.address.here:80>
ServerName xn--dfi5d.ws
ServerAlias www.xn--dfi5d.ws
DocumentRoot /home/foo/xn--dfi5d.ws/html
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I'm seeing the same results here.

Comment: I made that change (which makes sense, and I should've), however curl still finds www.naildrivin5.com, when I do `curl ❺➠.ws` it doesn't work, still.

If I set the "HOST" header to www.❺➠.ws, no dice, but setting the HOST header to the punyname works.  Is this expected?  I guess headers probably can't/shouldn't contain unicode?

Comment: I just went to www.❺➠.ws in Chrome and got the naildrivin5 site. When I cleared the cache (Ctrl-F5), it loaded the www.❺➠.ws site. I have been unable to locate information on clearing curl's cache. Also, curl retrieves the www.❺➠.ws page for me as expected with or without the www. Unfortunately, I didn't test that before you added the ServerAlias. You might try setting CacheDisable temporarily in your VirtualHost configuration to see if that helps. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_cache.html

Comment: Well, that didn't do anything.

I think I'm gonna mark this as correct, since, if I set the Host header in curl to the punycodename, all is good.